# Handle concurrency receive requests service bus azure

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We reach sometimes the maximum number of handles which is allowed at 4999 in Service Bus Azure.

We notice that it is due to the limit of concurrent request from receive one of our Function App.

How to manage this concurrency ?

For information, 3 functions are timing-triggers and send with Service Bus throught Javascript SDK many messages to `exemple` topic. On receiver side, only one function receive messages with functions bindings. We are developing the functions in Node.js

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like connections leaking, unless you think that you actually have 5,000 concurrent function executions.   Are you ensuring that any Service Bus client/sender you're using is closed and cleaned-up after when execution completes?

Comment: In fact, I think we don’t have 5000 concurrent function executions. 
We don’t close client/sender because it is not recommended in the documentation due to reconnection expensive operations. Is that correct ?

Comment: The challenge with the language workers is that ensuring reuse of clients is difficult. If a new client is created for each invocation and not closed, the connection will leak and count against your quota until it idles out and the service closes it (~20 mins).   That seems most likely what's happening here.   I'd suggest either using the trigger for all receives or ensuring that you explicitly close any consumers.  Opening an issue for the Functions team to ask how to ensure reuse may also be helpful: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues

Comment: What do you mean about using the trigger for all receives ?
In my case I got only one receiver

Comment: I mean changing the Function from timer-triggered to Service Bus-triggered, as that manages the receiver client and lifetime so that you don't need to.